# Refrencing a DLL file that has been installed via setup project, in a sub directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

I've created a project that uses a DLL that I've generated in another project. I've manually referenced the DLL via adding a reference to the output of the DLL project. However, I've now added a "Setup Project" (Deployment Project) and put the output of the DLL project in the File system on target machine (within a subfolder "AppDlls")

Once I install the application, it places the DLL files in the desired sub directory, but also places the manually referenced DLL in the same directory as the exe.

The question, how can I add the reference to the DLL file within a sub folder of the installation directory. If I add a reference to other project in the solution, the DLLs automatically get added in the same directory of the Main .exe. I'd like to be able to have all the DLLs in a sub folder of the installation directory, "AppDLLs", rather than have them in the same directory as the installed Application.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You are supposed to *only* add the output of the main EXE project to your setup.  Its dependencies come along for the ride, MSBuild ensures that they get copied.  So you probably ended up getting them copied twice, once from the EXE build directory and again by trying to put them in the subdirectory from the DLL projects.  That for one means that you probably never actually tested this and never once got them loaded from the subdir.  Putting DLLs in a subdirectory is a very bad practice and the CLR hates it.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the response, and sorry for the late reply. Yes, as I mentioned in the post, it does copy the dependencies twice. I did test it, hence why I mentioned I get it in two locations. Is there any reason why this is bad practice other than the "CLR hates it". The reason I want to do this is because I've got a lot DLLs and would like to organize them.